# Update log_statement value from all to none in EDB postgres

Tags: postgresql, enterprisedb

I want to change log_statement value from **all** to **none** on EDB 13 postgresql.conf file. Is the below command is sufficient to reflect above change that are updated in postgresql.conf file?

```
# su - enterprisedb 
# psql
# postgres> SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried above command and I am new to Postgres. Before running above command on production, I am seeking suggestions from Postgres experts :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `log_statement` is reloadable, at least on PG14. I was experimenting with log options last week and never had to restart the server to apply changes. (Assuming EDB hasn’t changed anything in the logging code, of course.)